# Python dict of dict Regex on keys

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm still getting to grips with dictionaries in Python.  Is it possible to reference the Key in a dict of dicts by using either a regex or a startswith function?

I have a dict of dicts in the following format and I am trying to do a general search for 'AreaOfInterest1','AreaOfInterest2','AreaOfInterest3' etc.  I make it general as I then refer the associated list value[0] to perform actions.

My dict of dicts would look something like...

```
FeatureDict = {
    "MATCHcode96":{
    'ID':'MATCHcode96',
    'AreaOfInterest1':['String 1','%',0],
    'AreaOfInterest2':['String 2','Avg',[]],
    'AreaOfInterest3':['String 3','Avg',[]],
    },
    "MATCHcode9F":{
    'ID':'MATCHcode9F',
    'AreaOfInterest1':['String 1','%',0],
    'AreaOfInterest2':['String 2','Avg',[]],
    },
}
```

The kind of functionality I am looking for is either to use startswith (like below) or otherwise try regex..

```
for dict in FeatureDict:
    if FeatureDict[dict]['ID'] in mypkt.Text:               
        if FeatureDict[dict][startswith.('AreaOfInterest')][0] in mypkt.Text:
            print 'found'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend using the [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function here. `if any(FeatureDict[dict][k].startswith('AreaOfInterest') and FeatureDict[dict][k][0] in mypkt.Text for k in FeatureDict[dict]): print 'found'`. Disclaimer: untested. And the downside of using any is that you can't save the value you found, but it's good for simple "found" conditionals.

Comment: Oh and, `dict` is not a good variable name because it shadows the built-in type of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

No, `dict` does not support lookups based on functions of the key or partial matches of the key. `dict` does support iteration, so you can do your own lookup, at a O(n) cost. (`dict` lookup is ordinarily O(1)).

```
for outer_key, outer_val in FeatureDict.items():
    if outer_val['ID'] in mypkt.Text:
        for inner_key, inner_val in outer_val:
            if inner_key.startswith('AreaOfInterest') and inner_val in mypkt.Text:
                print found
                break
```

Answer (score 1):

Just keep looping:

```
ids = ['MATCHcode9F']
area_ids = ['String 1']
for key in data:
    if data[key]['ID'] in ids:
        for inner_key in data[key]:
            if inner_key.startswith('AreaOfInterest') and data[key][inner_key][0] in area_ids:
                print('found')
```

So your code would look like

```
for key in FeatureDict:
    if FeatureDict[key]['ID'] in mypkt.Text:
        for inner_key in FeatureDict[key]:
            if inner_key.startswith('AreaOfInterest') and FeatureDict[key][inner_key][0] in mypkt.Text:
                print 'found'
```